# How to launch a Spark Streaming YARN application with Kerberos-Only Users?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, kerberos

1. The Problem: As expected, OS Users are able to launch and own a spark streaming application. However, when we try to run a job where the owner of the application is not an OS User, the spark streaming returns an error saying that the user was not found. As you can see in the output from the 'spark-submit' command:

```
main : run as user is 'user_name'
main : requested yarn user is 'user_name'
User 'user_name' not found
```

I already saw this error in some other forums and the recommendation was to created the OS-User, but unfortunately this is not an option here. In storm applications a Kerberos-Only User can be used in combination with an OS-User, but this seems not to be the case in spark.

2. What I have tried so far: The closest I could get was to use two OS Users, where one has 'read' access to the keytab file of the second one. I ran the application from one to 'impersonate' the second and the second appears as the owner. No errors appear as both are OS Users, but it does fail when I use a Kerberos-Only user as the second. Following you can see the submitted command for spark-streaming (BTW both are also HDFS-users, otherwise it would also not be possible to launch):

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --keytab /etc/security/keytabs/user_name.keytab 
--principal kerberosOnlyUser@LOCAL 
--files ./spark_jaas.conf#spark_jaas.conf,
./user_name_copy.keytab#user_name_copy.keytab --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./spark_jaas.conf" 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./spark_jaas.conf" 
--driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./spark_jaas.conf" 
--conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true --class ...
```

I also tried the alternative with the `--proxy-user` command, but the same error was returned.

Is it really not possible to use a Kerberos-only user in spark? Or is there a workaround?
The environment is:

```
Spark 2.3.0 on YARN.
Hadoop 2.7.3.
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: After authenticating the user (with Kerberos in your case), **by default**, Hadoop relies on the **OS** to retrieve the groups that this user belongs to. If the OS maps Kerberos users to Linux users _(via LDAP typically, using SSSD or Centrify)_ then it works out of the box.

Comment: In your case you must **change the Hadoop configuration** to map the groups directly to LDAP => change the Java class, configure the LDAP directory (or directories) to tap. Google that.

Comment: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_security/content/setting_up_hadoop_group_mappping_for_ldap_ad.html

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/GroupsMapping.html